# Checkbox change won't fire form submit via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I'm trying to build a webpage where you can search for specific media in a database. You have multiple checkboxes to filter data. The backend query is working fine.

The problem is that none of the checkboxes will submit the form via Ajax.
The alert("test") gets displayed. If I submit the form manually via the submitbutton the form is submitted and the data is shown.

HTML:

```
<form id = "extended_search_form" method = "post" action = "extended_search.cfm">
    <div id = "datatype_filter">
        <ul class = "selectbox">
            <li id = "datatype_filter_select">
                Bitte einen Dateityp wählen             
                <ul class = "checkboxes">
                <!--- checkboxes getting loaded on datatype_filter click --->
                <!--- example checkbox --->
                   <li>
                      <label><input name="datatype_filter_checkboxes" value="1" type="checkbox"> Fotograph</label>
                   </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#datatype_filter").on("change","input[name=datatype_filter_checkboxes]", function() {
    alert("test");
    $("#extended_search_form").unbind("submit").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.cfc?method=testSearch",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            error: function(event,jqhxr,ajaxSettings,error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }).done(function(result) {
            alert("Success");
        });
    });
});
```

What am I missing, that the form wont be submitted on the checkbox change event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `submit` event handler from `change` event handler and define it document ready handler.

You need to [`submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) the parent form in the checkbox change event handler.

```
$("#datatype_filter").on("change", "input[name=datatype_filter_checkboxes]", function () {
    $(this).closest('form').submit(); //Target parent form and submit it
});

$("#extended_search_form").off("submit").on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    console.log(formData);
    $.ajax({
        url: "test.cfc?method=testSearch",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        error: function (event, jqhxr, ajaxSettings, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }).done(function (result) {
        alert("Success");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line of code `$("#extended_search_form").unbind("submit").submit(function(e) {` this link is not required for form submission. and add id of form in `FormData` `var formData = new FormData($("#extended_search_form")[0]);`

```
$("#datatype_filter").on("change","input[name=datatype_filter_checkboxes]", function() {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($("#extended_search_form")[0]);
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.cfc?method=testSearch",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            error: function(event,jqhxr,ajaxSettings,error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }).done(function(result) {
            alert("Success");
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when a checkbox is clicked, you bind a [submit event](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) to the form but don't submit it. I believe your code would work if you added `$("#extended_search_form").submit()` to the end of your code (see example below)

```js
$("#datatype_filter").on("change","input[name=datatype_filter_checkboxes]", function() {
    alert("test");
    $("#extended_search_form").unbind("submit").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
            url: "test.cfc?method=testSearch",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            error: function(event,jqhxr,ajaxSettings,error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }).done(function(result) {
            alert("Success");
        });
    });
    $("#extended_search_form").submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id = "extended_search_form" method = "post" action = "extended_search.cfm">
    <div id = "datatype_filter">
        <ul class = "selectbox">
            <li id = "datatype_filter_select">
                Bitte einen Dateityp wählen
            </li>
            <ul class = "checkboxes">
                <!--- checkboxes getting loaded on datatype_filter click --->
                <!--- example checkbox --->
                <label><input name="datatype_filter_checkboxes" value="1" type="checkbox"> Fotograph</label>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
</form>
```